# IOS6 Mapkit licensing, terms of use

Tags: licensing, mapkit, ios6, ios6-maps

In IOS6 map data was replaced from Google to Apple's own map data.

In the past, when MapKit was used you had to accept Google Maps licensing and terms of use (https://developers.google.com/maps/iphone/terms). What is the situation with the new MapKit and its new map data? E.g. GoogleMaps was not enabled to use in commercial apps by free, to use it you had to buy some premium packages. Etc.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear, do you mean to ask if AppleMaps can be used in a commercial app?

Comment: What is not clear? Is it enabled to use IOS Maps in commercial apps for free? If not, what are the terms of use?

Comment: Yes it is free, just as Google Maps (as part of MapKit) was. Maybe you're mixing up the Google Maps API that people use on websites with the iOS classes that can definitely be used in commercial iOS maps.

Comment: No, Google Maps based Mapkit NEVER was free for commercial apps. Google based MapKit was ruled also by Google Maps API terms and conditions. And it is only free for free apps. (I asked it from the official Apple developer support about a year ago)

Comment: I have sold apps using the mapkit framework via the iTunes store for more than a year and had no GM fees. I know another app developer who has been doing it for 3 years, same deal. MapKit is and always has been free for use in commercial apps. If you were actually trying to sell their maps as if they were your own there would be an issue. But having a map in your app is and always has been free.

Comment: Yesm if you did not violate this: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq Hopefully, you didn't :)

Comment: Pls. check my link in my question, it is there.

Comment: No, no, no. Using Apple's MapKit library does NOT mean you need to pay Google anything. The very first question on the page you linked to asks "What are the Google Maps APIs" and lists them as; the Javascript API; the Flash API and the Static API. The iPhone Map API (MapKit https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) is covered by https://developers.google.com/maps/iphone/terms and is totally free (though restricted) to use.

Comment: ...and the first highlighted row at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html  is: 
Important: In iOS 5.1 and earlier, the Map Kit framework uses the Google Mobile Maps (GMM) service to provide map data. Use of specific classes of this framework (and their associated interfaces) is subject to the Google Mobile Maps terms of service. You can find these terms of service at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html.

Comment: It is the answer I got from Apple some months ago: "The MapKit framework is offered as part of the Software Development Kit by Google. As such, it is governed by the Google Map Kit Terms of Service. Also keep in mind that you are bound by the Apple Developer Program License Agreement. You do not need additional licenses from Apple, but everything you do must be within the license to which you've already agreed. You can find this in the Member Center at developer.apple.com under "Your Account" and "Legal Agreements."  We cannot speak on behalf of Google's licenses."

Comment: No. Read the iPhone specific terms that I, and now you, have linked to. Also read this from Ed Parsons of Google. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929124/usage-limits-to-the-google-maps-api-impact-on-usage-of-mapkit-in-ios  You can not charge *just* for adding Google Maps to your app, but if you are charging for the whole app, be it fleet tracking or rabbit hunting, you're fine.

Comment: Then I don't understand, I am not a lawyer and there is no a clear yes or no for this question. For me. And my main problem is that Apple Developer support did not answer my question about the new MapKit. That's why I asked it here. And as I see no answer yet.

Comment: I've repeated the answer over and over again. If you can find one single case of an app that has to pay to use MapKit (not taking about Google's other APIs here) then you may have reason to doubt me or the literally hundreds of other developers that use MapKit in commercial apps. I've linked to the terms that say you can use it and don't say they will charge you for it, I even quoted Ed Parsons of Google Maps, I'm not sure what else you want.

Comment: In case of vehicle tracking/fleet management apps you should pay.

Comment: No you should not. Maybe on a website, but you're asking about iOS apps so that is all I am answering about.

Comment: In the document we linked (https://developers.google.com/maps/iphone/terms), section 10. License Restrictions, 10.9 (c) dispatch, fleet management, business asset tracking, or similar enterprise applications (the Google Maps API can be used to track assets (such as cars, buses or other vehicles) as long as the tracking application is made available to the public without charge. For example, you may offer a free, public Maps API Implementation that displays real-time public transit or other transportation status information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular subject is very obscure. I've been looking into this matter for the past 2 days... so here are my 2 cents:

- Mapkit is one thing, GMAP terms and conditions is another thing. The fact that Mapkit is free does not mean that the map provider is going to give you the data for free and allow any kind of use.
- If you are going to show vehicles' locations on map and those vehicles are your customers (you charge for the service), you need GMAP Business edition and Premier API. There's no way around it, *no matter if the iPhone app is free* and this is also *regardless of the framework (Mapkit)*.
- Addressing the original question about if Apple Maps is going to be free, there is no way to know at least right now... No one knows. We can *speculate* that it will be free, for the simple fact that if it's not, it will break current functionality of other tracking applications that were developed in the time of iOS 5 where GMAP was the current data provider. We can also speculate that, since GMAP Business is $10k per year + traffic, it's not going to be free!

And most important of all, about the "Apps that use location-based APIs for dispatch, fleet management, or emergency services will be rejected," note that it says "location-based APIs", which your app "will not use" because you already have the position data on your servers. The idea behind that sentence is to avoid apps that will track the iPhone user in real-time. You can have to most amazing Fleet Management app and never use the built-in GPS antenna, simply because you don't need it.

Sources:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing
- https://developers.google.com/maps/iphone/terms
- http://www.google.com.pr/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-faq.html (check out question "What is the cost of Google Maps API for Business?")

Apps that are already doing it:

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fleetmatics/id441922434?mt=8
- https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/scania-fleet-management/id513863147?mt=8

Hope that helps.-

Comment: Thx Nick, the clearest thoughts I've ever heared about this topic

Answer (score 3):

Starting again since the comments became too long. Essential points are

1) You never had to pay to use MapKit in a commercial app (noted that if you charge solely for map access then you violate the terms - no mention of what action gets taken, also some people confuse the Javascript API terms with the MapKit terms).

1.2) With exceptions as noted in 10.9 of the license agreement

2) Using the MapKit under iOS 6 shouldn't be seen as any different to using ApplicationKit, UIKit, or any other framework Apple provides. You can use them in commercial apps.

Comment: 1. In the document we linked (developers.google.com/maps/iphone/terms), section 10. License Restrictions, 10.9 (c) dispatch, fleet management, business asset tracking, or similar enterprise applications (the Google Maps API can be used to track assets (such as cars, buses or other vehicles) as long as the tracking application is made available to the public without charge. For example, you may offer a free, public Maps API Implementation that displays real-time public transit or other transportation status information. 2. It would be different, because map providers come into view.

Comment: Edit the above answer to note that exception to the rule

Comment: Exceptions at 10.9 are very important. So you must pay to Google if you use MapKit in that kind of commercial apps. Thanks anyway! Do you know anything about the new IOS6 MapKit? Does it have that kind of restrictions? I did not find any info about this. Thanks Craig!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the same as any other API provided by Apple. No reason to think otherwise.

Comment: As a developer, who mainly develops fleet management apps it would be the news of the year. :) Map data licensing and pricing is always a critical question at my work, and never met free data, that has good quality/coverage for my apps (except OSM for some areas).

Comment: Sad news for me: "Apps that use location-based APIs for dispatch, fleet management, or emergency services will be rejected" https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html