# License for MapKit iOS Development

Tags: ios, mapkit

for developing an App with MapKit inside, i need informations about the terms of use and licenses for commercial usage. I already asked google about that topic and looked at Apple's pages, but there was no result.

The only one i've found was this: [IOS6 Mapkit licensing, terms of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502393/ios6-mapkit-licensing-terms-of-use)
But MapKit does not contain Google Maps anymore.

Maybe you can tell me something about it or find the informations.

Comment: Since you are using iOS, you might have an iOS Developer Portal, you are already accepting an agreement of license to use anything of iOS for your development, there is no problem, its all free for use. No license required to use any control that is developed by Apple for Apple, earlier Google Maps was the part of Map, but no now.

Comment: Also, not sure your experience with submitting apps to Apple for app review, but they are relatively thorough. From my experience, they would catch most issues like this and tell you to change it without penalty.